# BG Colour menu does not seem to appear once full toolbar is configured on TestLink 1.9.16

Tags: ckeditor, testlink

[image]

CKeditor version 4.6
Browser : Firefox.54
OS :Linux 3.13.0-36-generic

I tried to configure the cfkeditor within the testlink tool and provided the configurations as below in order to get the full toolbar. However, I cannot seem to get the BGColor menu option.

steps
1.configure the cfg/tl_ckeditor_config.js as shown below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHXbU.png)

2.call the menu name Full within the config.ini.php as below[2]

Note: How can I obtain the BGColor menu button.

## [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHXbU.png) cfg/tl_ckeditor_config.js

```
 config.toolbar_Full =
    [
    ['Source','-','Save','NewPage','Preview','-','Templates'],
    ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Print', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt'],
    ['Undo','Redo','-','Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'],
    ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField'],
    '/',
    ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Subscript','Superscript'],
    ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote','CreateDiv'],
    ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
    ['BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl' ],
    ['Link','Unlink','Anchor'],
    ['Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak'],
    '/',
    ['Styles','Format','Font','FontSize'],
    ['TextColor','BGColor'],
    ['Maximize','ShowBlocks','-','About']
    ];
```

## [2] config.ini.php

`
$tlCfg->gui->text_editor['steps_design'] = array('type' => 'ckeditor','toolbar' => 'Full',
'configFile' => 'cfg/tl_ckeditor_config.js',
'height' => 50);

$tlCfg->gui->text_editor['execution'] = array( 'type' => 'none');
$tlCfg->gui->text_editor['edit_execution'] = array( 'type' => 'none', 'cols' => 80, 'rows' => 20);
$tlCfg->gui->text_editor['display_execution_notes'] = array('type' => 'none', 'cols' => 80, 'rows' => 20);
`

Answer (score 1):

According to ckeditor's [documentation](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_colorbutton.html]documentation), additional optional plugins are needed to support the BG Color feature.

On the same page, relative to those two items, they also say: (bold emphasis mine)

> The Text and Background Color feature **does not create** semantically
>   meaningful content. Even if you adjust the color list to match the
>   style of your website, your users will be able to arbitrarily apply
>   colors to text elements without any consistency.
>
> A much better idea for creating semantic content and maintaining
>   consistent styling across your website is to adjust the Styles
>   drop-down list to include some colors that could be applied to
>   user-created content and would still be consistent with your website
>   design.

Probably not what you want to hear, but now you know.